# Variable height for page header in reportviewer

Tags: .net, reportviewer

I have a report written in rdlc that would need to have expendable height. In this particular case, I have two adresse field which can take from on to five lignes each. If I set the height to the minimum height possible, the fields get cropped so I don't see the whole thing. However, if I set the height to the biggest value possible, then I get huge gaps when the adress is too small.

What I would like is to have a small header but expendable. I search far and wide and this does not seem possible out of the box. Is there a way to do this ?

Thanks